# How to insert options in Drop down menu with help of getElementsByName

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am creating multiple row in a table and in my table first cell is drop down menu.
Again, next row with first cell is drop down menu.
I have data in an array. I am not able to set values with getElementById.

and same syntax for getElementsByName is not working.

```
$("#btn-add-row").click(function(){
    var row="<tr>  <td><select id='country'  name='ct' style='width:275px;'></select></td> <td><input type='text' name='Count' class='form-control'></td> <td><input type='text' required name='Rate' class='form-control'></td> <td><input type='text'  name='Bprice' class='form-control' readonly></td> <td><input type='text' required name='Quantity' class='form-control'></td> <td><input type='text' required name='Total' class='form-control'></td> <td><input type='button' value='x' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-row-remove'> </td>  </tr>";
    $("#product_tbody").append(row);
                            
    var countr ;
            
    for(var ia=0;ia<data1.length;ia++){ 
        countr[ia]=data1[ia].Product;
    }

    $("#ct").select2({
        data: countr
    }); 

 document.getElementsByName('ct').innerHTML="testing";
             $("#ct").eq(0).val("testing");


});
```

Comment: I see no vanilla JS but jQuery and see no line where either getElements... was used

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=jQuery+insert+select+in+table+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items

Comment: You cannot duplicate ID attributes. The above function would generate duplicate IDs if invoked multiple times.